# How to create level 3 menu in WordPress via wp_get_nav_menu_items()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I create a function which grouped the level 1 menu and level 2 menu, I want to grouped the level 3 menu via wp_get_nav_menu_items(). Any one can help me how I can grouped the level 3 menu in a array.

```
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {
    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
    $menu_level_one = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu_level_one[$m->ID] = array();
            $menu_level_one[$m->ID]['ID']          =   $m->ID;
            $menu_level_one[$m->ID]['title']       =   $m->title;
            $menu_level_one[$m->ID]['url']         =   $m->url;
            $menu_level_one[$m->ID]['children']    =   array();
        }
    }
    $menu_level_two = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
            $menu_level_two[$m->ID] = array();
            $menu_level_two[$m->ID]['ID']       =   $m->ID;
            $menu_level_two[$m->ID]['title']    =   $m->title;
            $menu_level_two[$m->ID]['url']      =   $m->url;
            $menu_level_one[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $menu_level_two[$m->ID];
        }
    }
    return $menu_level_one;
}
```